# How to write valid JSON data in logs in java Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Logs file currently

`"message":"{\"productID\":\"999\",\"productName\":\"Shoes",\"productCost\":\"1200\"}"`
the data is fine but JSON format it not valid

Code currently used to convert a model into JSON

```
 public static String test(Object obj) {
        ObjectMapper ow = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            ow.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            return ow.writer().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Log code used to write in log file.

`logg.info(MainClass.test(productBean);`

Log configurations in logback.xml. logger I have used is of **org.slf4j**

``

```
<appender name="testLog">
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
<level>info</level>
</filter>
<file>C:/Logs/logs.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>C:/Logs/logs.log</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name = "com.demo" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="testLog" />
</logger>
```

``

Comment: I don't get it. You're getting valid JSON output in your log, and you want to change it to invalid JSON?

Comment: Sorry I just checked if you copy that JSON with \ from log file it is not getting parsed, So I wanted to know if we can remove these \ from the message.
 @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: How exactly do you log the statement? Do you use any JSON based log format or how does your log configuration look like?

Comment: updated the question with configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the logback.xml where we specify our appenders and loggers we need to add the encoder tag for our appender.

```
<encoder>
<pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} | %-5level [%thread] %message%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String formattedMessage = message.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Because the backslash is the escaping character in a regular expression replaceAll() receives one as parameter, which has to be escaped too.

Comment: I have updated the question the problem is \ is added automatically as the data contains "

Comment: actually your json string formed is incorrect it should be
"{\"productID\":\"999\",\"productName\":\"Shoes\",\"productCost\":\"1200\"}"
there is issue in escaping characters due to which it is not forming a string you can check on online compiler and after using the above replace on this string it worked fine on sysout.